# ¿Como sumar totales diferentes por columnas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día

Tengo la siguiente tabla en `MySQL`:

```
id     |    pais    |  categoria
193    |     BR     |     A
188    |     BR     |     A
133    |     BR     |     B
145    |     BR     |     C
124    |     CA     |     A
165    |     CA     |     B
113    |     CA     |     B
177    |     CA     |     C
197    |     MX     |     A
213    |     MX     |     B
208    |     MX     |     C
222    |     MX     |     C
```

Quiero obtener el total de categoría por cada país en diferente columna, es decir:

```
categoria  |  totalBR  |  totalCA  |  totalMX
    A      |    2      |    1      |    1
    B      |    1      |    2      |    1
    C      |    1      |    1      |    2
```

Se me ocurre crear una tabla temporal para el total por país y categoría pero creo que no seria tan buena idea ya que tendría que crear 9 tablas temporales y después hacerles un `union all`

UPDATE

La 1er tabla la obtengo de una consulta `SQL` y como no pude obtener el total de diferentes columnas de la 1er tabla, modifique mi consulta `SQL` obteniendo la siguiente tabla:

```
  |      id     |    pais    |  categoriaBR  | categoriaCA  | categoriaMX  |
  |      193    |     BR     |     A         |     null     |    null      |
  |      188    |     BR     |     A         |     null     |    null      |
  |      133    |     BR     |     B         |     null     |    null      |
  |      145    |     BR     |     C         |     null     |    null      |
  |      124    |     CA     |    null       |       A      |    null      |
  |      165    |     CA     |    null       |       B      |    null      |
  |      113    |     CA     |    null       |       B      |    null      |
  |      177    |     CA     |    null       |       C      |    null      |
  |      197    |     MX     |    null       |     null     |      A       |
  |      213    |     MX     |    null       |     null     |      B       |
  |      208    |     MX     |    null       |     null     |      C       |
  |      222    |     MX     |    null       |     null     |      C       |
```

y cree 9 tablas temporales

```
#------------------------------------------------categoriasBR------------------------------------------------
DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaBR1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaBR1 AS ( 
    SELECT 1 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaBR = 'A' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaBR2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaBR2 AS ( 
    SELECT 2 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaBR = 'B' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaBR3;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaBR3 AS ( 
    SELECT 3 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaBR = 'C' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

#------------------------------------------------categoriasCA------------------------------------------------
    DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaCA4;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaCA4 AS ( 
    SELECT 1 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaCA = 'A' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaCA5;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaCA5 AS ( 
    SELECT 2 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaCA = 'B' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaCA6;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaCA6 AS ( 
    SELECT 3 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaCA = 'C' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

#---------------------------------------------------categoriasMX--------------------------------------------------
DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaMX7;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaMX7 AS ( 
    SELECT 1 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaMX = 'A' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaMX8;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaMX8 AS ( 
    SELECT 2 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaMX = 'B' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);

DROP temporary table IF EXISTS categoriaMX9;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoriaMX9 AS ( 
    SELECT 3 as id, ifnull(sum(case when categoriaMX = 'C' then 1 else 0 end),0) as 'Total'
        FROM tabla
);
#------------------------------------UNION DE TODO---------------------------------------------------------------    
select 'A' as Categoria, categoriaBR1.Total as TotalBR, categoriaCA1.Total as TotalCA, categoriaMX1.Total as TotalMX from categoriaBR1
        INNER JOIN categoriaCA1 ON categoriaBR1.id = categoriaCA1.id
        INNER JOIN categoriaMX1 ON categoriaBR1.id = categoriaMX1.id
    union all
select 'B' as Categoria, categoriaBR2.Total as TotalBR, categoriaCA2.Total as TotalCA, categoriaMX2.Total as TotalMX from categoriaBR2
        INNER JOIN categoriaCA2 ON categoriaBR2.id = categoriaCA2.id
        INNER JOIN categoriaMX2 ON categoriaBR2.id = categoriaMX2.id
    union all
select 'C' as Categoria, categoriaBR3.Total as TotalBR, categoriaCA3.Total as TotalCA, categoriaMX3.Total as TotalMX from categoriaBR3
        INNER JOIN categoriaCA3 ON categoriaBR3.id = categoriaCA3.id
        INNER JOIN categoriaMX3 ON categoriaBR3.id = categoriaMX3.id
```

cabe mencionar que con la creación de las 9 tablas temporales obtengo el resultado que quiero mas la idea que tengo es llegar al mismo resultado sin tanta tabla temporal

Comment: @Flxtr Hice 9 tablas temporales sumando el total por categoría, les agregué un ID a las temporales, después les hice un inner join para obtener el totalBR, totalCA, totalMX por categoría y uni las categorías con union all pero siento que me la estoy complicando

Comment: Tienes razón quizás no lo agregue en un principio porque siento que estoy creando una tormenta en un vaso de agua con tanta tabla temporal pero ya hice la actualización y ya agregue lo que tengo, cabe mencionar que con lo que hice obtengo el resultado deseado mas me gustaría obtener el mismo resultado pero sin tanta tabla temporal

Comment: @ElCóndor Te deje un ejemplo para que lo puedas hacer más simple, eficiente y elegante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas tratar los datos como si fuera una tabla de tipo pivote. Se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
  category,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'BR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'BR',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'CA',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'MX' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'MX'
FROM foo
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category;
```

Te dejo el [ejemplo funcionando aquí en sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e78d10/1).

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba, como me lo imagine me la estaba complicando demasiado y de la forma en que tu lo haces es eficiente, simple y elegante como mencionas, muchas gracias!